# How to correctly use LUIS ML-features?

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding, nlu

I just stumbled over the new "ML-features" in LUIS and I am not sure if I really understand how to use them correctly. The documentation seems very abstract and vague to me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature

Besides a good general explanation a solution for the following example would be very welcome:

**Example**

Intent: OpenABox

Sample utterances: "open the green box", "open the azure box".

Entity: ColorEntity (no prebuilt entity).

The color should understand "green", "blue", "azure" and "olive", where "olive" should be regarded as synonym to "green" and "azure" to "blue".

**Solution Proposal**

I assume you would have to

- Add an intent
- Add a list-entity, that lists all colors and assigns their synonyms?
- Add a phrase list, that again lists some, but maybe not all, colors, without respect to their meaning?
- Make the ML-feature global?
- Mark the values as interchangable?
- Add a ML-entity, and assign the list entity as well as the phrase list as features?
- Make the list-entity-feature required?
- Add sample utterances and mark the entities with the list-entity? Or with the ML-entity? Or both?
- Add the ML-Entity as feature to the intent? Or the phrase list? Or the list-entity? Or none at all?

Is it correct, that there is no way to confirm the correct resolution of "olive" to its canonical form "green" using the test panel? So I have to use the API to test this?

**The Model**

This model has been created as described above. It seems to do its job. But is this really the optimal way to do it? There seems to be a lot of redundancy in there.

```
{
  "luis_schema_version": "7.0.0",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "None",
      "features": []
    },
    {
      "name": "OpenABox",
      "features": [
        {
          "modelName": "ColorMLEntity",
          "isRequired": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "ColorMLEntity",
      "children": [],
      "roles": [],
      "features": [
        {
          "featureName": "ColorPhraseList",
          "isRequired": false
        },
        {
          "modelName": "ColorListEntity",
          "isRequired": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hierarchicals": [],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [
    {
      "name": "ColorListEntity",
      "subLists": [
        {
          "canonicalForm": "green",
          "list": [
            "olive"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "blue",
          "list": [
            "azure"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "roles": []
    }
  ],
  "prebuiltEntities": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "open the azure box",
      "intent": "OpenABox",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "ColorMLEntity",
          "startPos": 9,
          "endPos": 13,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "open the green box",
      "intent": "OpenABox",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "ColorMLEntity",
          "startPos": 9,
          "endPos": 13,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "ColorTest",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "tokenizerVersion": "1.0.0",
  "patternAnyEntities": [],
  "regex_entities": [],
  "phraselists": [
    {
      "name": "ColorPhraseList",
      "mode": true,
      "words": "green,blue,azure,olive",
      "activated": true,
      "enabledForAllModels": false
    }
  ],
  "regex_features": [],
  "patterns": [],
  "settings": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features are supposed to be signals relevant to an intent, or an entity.
So for this example,

- Create an ML entity "ColorEntity",
- Label the utterances
- Add ColorEntity as a feature for the intent
- Then you can add a feature to ColorEntity, either a list entity or phrase list, no need for both.